# Tomcat 7.0 Connection pooling - jdbc driver exception

Tags: java, mysql, maven, tomcat, jdbc

I want to implement connection pooling on my Tomcat server. Here is my context.xml file (placed under `WebContent/META-INF/context.xml`:

```
<Context path="/evappserver" reloadable="true">
    <Resource
          name="jdbc/evapp"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          initialSize="34"
          maxActive="377"
          maxIdle="233"
          minIdle="89"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="34"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
          username="root"
          password=""
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evapp?allowMultiQueries=true"
     />
</Context>
```

I have a **maven** project so the mysql jdbc driver is imported via the `pom.xml` file, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my java code which throws the exception:

```
    Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext  = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/evapp"); //here is the exception
```

Here is the exception:

```
May 13, 2014 10:39:58 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:488)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at com.evappserver.dblayer.DBType.<init>(DBType.java:62)
    at com.evappserver.dblayer.MySqlDB.<init>(MySqlDB.java:16)
    at com.evappserver.logiclayer.BaseLogic.getMainDbConnection(BaseLogic.java:19)
    at com.evappserver.logiclayer.PasswordLoginLogic.doLogin(PasswordLoginLogic.java:27)
    at com.evappserver.servlets.PasswordLoginServlet.doGet(PasswordLoginServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 38 more
```

Is there something wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should include the driver for MySQL in your tomcat /lib folder instead of deploying it along with your web application.  This way the server will find the proper classes to instantiate your connection pool and everything should go fine.

Comment: Where exactly this folder located? `WebContent\WEB_INF\lib`?

Comment: Nope, there should be a /lib directory in the Tomcat server directory.

Comment: there is no such directory. should I create one and delete the dependancy from the pom.xml?

Comment: That looks very strange.  Please note that I am not talking about your Eclipse (if you use Eclipse) project, but about the directory where your Tomcat server is installed.  Please look for it since it should have a /lib folder in it, where you can place any JDBC driver you need to define your connection pool.  And yes, once you do this, if you program to pure JDBC interfaces, you do not need the dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: I think I don't know where to look for it. In Eclipse (which I do use) I have servers folder and under it the tomcat server which is name is "Tomcat v7.0...". Where can I find the directive you are talking about?

Comment: In your Servers tab under Eclipse, you should be able to right-click each server, have a look at its properties and see there which is the path where each server is installed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52577/discussion-between-vlio20-and-jorge-b)

Answer (score 1):

check if the classpath of your project contains the file mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar. Did maven run without problems?

Comment: Yes, there is! Before I started building the pooling mechanism I had ordinary connection, and it worked fine...

Comment: you can try to add MySQL binary jar to the application WEB-INF/lib directory

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem. For a reason unknown to me, putting the `mysql-connector-java*.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` no longer works in Ubuntu LTS 14.04

I solved it by copying this file (and this file alone) to `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` and restarted tomcat7 as a service service tomcat7 restart and everything sprang to life.

Best of luck